# Is there a way to get data from a render_template response in Flask?

Tags: python, json, rest, flask

So I'm working on writing tests for a webapp and the code one of my teammates wrote returns `render_template('some_page.html', data=data)`. Is there a way to access the data from the response? In my test, I do this (let's just call the route that returns this '/route'):

```
def testRoute(self):
    with self.client:
        self.client.post('/test/login/')    # this logs test user in
        response = self.client.get('/route')
        print response.data
```

And it prints the code (HTML/JS) that is in the some_page.html file. However, if in the route, I call `print data` right before it returns, it prints the JSON I want. So I know that the JSON passed to render_template is what I want—is there any way I can get this?

Comment: No, the kwargs passed into `render_template()` are used by Jinja2 to render the template, they are only available in that context.

Comment: @PJSantoro Is there a way this could be refactored to make this possible?

Comment: You could use selenium to test on web pages.